# ANSI C : snprintf allocating issue

Tags: c, printf

I encounter this issue when using the `snprintf()` function. I want to concat multiple strings.

I have a struct `msg` defined as

```
struct timerMessage { 
  char txncode[4]; 
  char date[8]; 
  char time[6]; 
  char mac[16]; 
  char userid[32]; 
  char instid[9]; 
  char merchcode[2]; 
  char seqno[3]; 
  char data[100]; 
} msg;
```

with these values:

```
{txncode = "9902", date = "08082015", time = "172936", mac = ' ' <repeats 16 times>, 
  userid = ' ' <repeats 32 times>, instid = "         ", merchcode = "  ", seqno = "001", 
  data = "FILE1TEST11|1P", '\000' <repeats 85 times>}
```

and this is how I concat the strings:

```
snprintf(msgbuffer,sizeof(msgbuffer),"%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s",msg.txncode,
msg.date,msg.time,msg.mac,msg.userid,msg.instid,msg.merchcode,msg.seqno,msg.data);
```

UPDATE: MCVE

struct msg

```
   char txncode[4] ,date[8], time[6], mac[16], userid[32], instid[9], merchcode[2], seqno[3], data[100];
```

var

```
   sprintf(msg.txncode,  "%s","9901");
    sprintf(msg.date,     "%002d%002d%002d",month,day,year);
    sprintf(msg.time,     "%002d%002d%002d",hr,min,sec);
    sprintf(msg.mac,      "% 16s",          " ");
    sprintf(msg.userid,   "% 32s",          " ");
    sprintf(msg.instid,   "% 9s",           " ");
    sprintf(msg.merchcode,"% 2s",           " ");
    sprintf(msg.seqno,"%003d",1);
    snprintf(msg.data,sizeof(msg.data),"%s|%s","FILE1TEST11","1P");
```

the result of concatenation:

```
"990208082015172936", ' ' (repeats 59 times), "001FILE1TEST11|1P0808"
```

the result should be:

```
"990208082015172936", ' ' (repeats 59 times), "001FILE1TEST11|1P"
```

Comment: Please show us the complete definition of your `msg` structure.

Comment: It looks like you are telling printf that you will pass a pointer but instead you are passing a character. I think you meant to pass "\000" as the last parameter? Single quotes mean something very different !

Comment: @Rene Last line of the question, it is 99.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try turning on warnings: `-Wall -Wextra` for *gcc* / *clang*. It should warn you if your format string does not match the rest of the arguments.

Comment: @rakeb.void the code is also applicable to C++

Comment: @MichaelWalz ` struct timerMessage
{
   char txncode[4];
   char date[8];
   char time[6];
   char mac[16];
   char userid[32];
   char instid[9];
   char merchcode[2];
   char  seqno[3];
   char data[100];

}msg;`

Comment: @hey: please update your question instead of dumping code into a comment. Or better post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What compiler/platform are you using? From the looks of it your compiler's implementation of `snprintf()` didn't write the terminating `'\0'` at the end of the string.

Comment: @Wernsey gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: @hey Judging from the `struct timerMessage` you posted above, the first problem is that the members of the `struct timerMessage` doesn't have enough space for the terminating NULL character: for example `char txncode[4];` should be `char txncode[5];` so that there is enough space for the `"9902"` and for the `\0` at the end. 
I'm not sure if this causes your problem, but I suggest fixing it first.

Comment: @Wernsey ok I will fix that first thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one issue here. In all the character arrays you are filling all the available position with values and none of the position can contain `NULL ('/0')` character. Modify your structure by adding one character in each character array as shown below and you'll get the desired result.

```
  3 struct timerMessage {
  4   char txncode[5];
  5   char date[9];
  6   char time[7];
  7   char mac[17];
  8   char userid[33];
  9   char instid[10];
 10   char merchcode[3];
 11   char seqno[4];
 12   char data[100];
 13 } msg;
```